# Fix tsconfig baseURL

Tags: typescript, vite, react-typescript

I don't want my import to be `../../` as the image below
[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA7rO.png)

Then I add

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
    "*": ["*"],
}
```

into my tsconfig.js

But when I change my import to be

```
import { degreeToDirection, formatServerTime } from 'utils';
import { IMEITrackResponse } from 'interface';
import { RootState } from 'store';
```

and run `yarn run dev`
I got this error

```
Failed to resolve import "utils" from "src\components\TableGrid\TableGrid.tsx". Does the file exist?
14:43:43 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "utils" from "src\components\TableGrid\TableGrid.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

Here is my folder stucture
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS759.png)

I don't know why it can not find the utils from the Folder Structure

Comment: `from 'utils'` refers to a directory and not a file - you should use `from 'utils/filename'` instead. Also your use of `paths` seems really strange...